# How to increment time in term of minutes

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to make an algorithm to increase time in term of minutes. I did it manually, it works fine. But, if the start date is about 1, 2 years ago, and i have to increase each 10 minutes, it take too much time.
here is the code i did, and as i said, it works fine, but takes too much time if the start and end date are far away.

```
int inc = 40;
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(50);//new DateTime(2013,9,6,18,40,0,DateTimeKind.Local);//DateTime.Today.AddHours(10).AddMinutes(50);
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(18).AddMinutes(35);//DateTime.Now;
List<DateTime> timeList = new List<DateTime>();
//while (startTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(inc))
while (startTime < endTime.AddMinutes(inc))
{
    timeList.Add(startTime);
    startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(inc);
}
```

StartDate: 12/9/2019 8:50
EndDate: 12/9/2019 18:35

Increase each 40 minutes.

So, the result is:

```
12/09/2016 8:50:00
12/09/2016 9:30:00
12/09/2016 10:10:00
12/09/2016 10:50:00
12/09/2016 11:30:00
12/09/2016 12:10:00
12/09/2016 12:50:00
12/09/2016 13:30:00
12/09/2016 14:10:00
12/09/2016 14:50:00
12/09/2016 15:30:00
12/09/2016 16:10:00
12/09/2016 16:50:00
12/09/2016 17:30:00
12/09/2016 18:10:00
12/09/2016 18:50:00
```

I need just last 2 lines:

```
12/09/2016 18:10:00
12/09/2016 18:50:00
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you need "endTime - 20 minutes", and "endTime - 10 minutes"?

Comment: Sorry? I don`t understand what you said.

Comment: Or something similar to Gus' question, but taking into account that the difference between start and end may not be exactly divisible by your increment?

Comment: I guess we're both a bit unsure about your exact requirements. Why only the last two lines? Is it 10 seconds, or is it 40 second increments?

Comment: Not always will be exactly divisible.. the increment (minutes) could be different. Also the start and end date.

Comment: It is 40 minutes increment (for this example)

Comment: So, starting at the start time, step by a certain increment, and get the value just before and just after your end time? What about if exactly on the end time?

Comment: Yes, starting at the start time, step by a certain increment (in minutes) and get the last 2 values: before and after the end time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate the minutes of the last two intervals to avoid looping:

```
var timeSpan = endTime - startTime;
var intervals = (int)timeSpan.TotalMinutes / inc;

// In case the endTime is aligned with the interval:
if ((int)timeSpan.TotalMinutes % inc == 0)
    intervals--;

startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(intervals * inc);
timeList.Add(startTime);
startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(inc);
timeList.Add(startTime);
```

Here is a slightly more elegant version:

```
var intervals = Math.Ceiling(timeSpan.TotalMinutes / inc);  

startTime = startTime.AddMinutes((intervals - 1) * inc);
timeList.Add(startTime);
startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(inc);
timeList.Add(startTime);
```

Here is a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/M1Z7Bn

Try different values (e.g. `35`, `50`, and `55`) for `AddMinutes()` at:

```
var end = DateTime.Today.AddHours(18).AddMinutes(35);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> CreateIntervals(this DateTime start, TimeSpan interval)
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return start;
        start = start + interval;
    }
}

var timeList = startTime.CreateInterval(interval).Take(40).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your minutes are fixed for the loop iteration and you are not doing anything fancy with the output. Have you tried to compare the performance against native long by converting to timestamp for the sake of this loop and only convert on the fly to a date where you need to use the date(s). I also suggest as a alternative and for better performance when working with dates to use the Joda library.

Here are my 2 cents:

```
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Two years ago
    long startTime = Math.subtractExact(System.currentTimeMillis(), 31536000000L);

    long instanceTime = startTime;

    ArrayList<Long> dateList = new ArrayList<>();

    while(instanceTime < endTime){
        instanceTime += 60000L; // Ten minute increment
        dateList.add(instanceTime);
    }
```